# UITableView section deletion control

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

How can I display a deletion control for an entire section like in iOS's Contacts app?

[image: Here is how the control looks.]

Comment: Could you please post an image for us unfamiliar with how the deletion control for a section may look?

Comment: Or is that just a very customized UITableViewCell?